# Giving object's send-method an other method with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

This one works:

```
Beer.all.send(:sort)
```

and also it works with block:

```
Beer.all.sort_by{|b| b.name}
Beer.all.sort_by(&:name)
```

But when I give a executable block to send-method like this:

```
Beer.all.send(:sort_by{|b| b.name})
Beer.all.send(:sort_by(&:name))
```

I get syntax error. Is there any alternative way in Ruby to give an executable block to send-method?

Comment: Please read Ruby first to know how stuffs work

Comment: If you want to pass an argument into method, then it's usually impossible.

Comment: Do you think `:sort_by{|b| b.name}` is a valid Ruby `Symbol` object ?

Comment: Good point, it is not.

Comment: Humm.. `Beer.order("name desc").all` to.. in the DB level.

Comment: Yep I was more confused about the syntax and the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) did not tell me enough. But for the peformance, wouldn't it be better to sort in the browser with javascript instead of many DB queries..?

Comment: Ah, I see. The syntax can take some getting used to. As to performance, it is slower to sort in JavaScript than in the DB. (Though there are a lot of factors like the browser, user's device, number of records, type of DB, etc.) However, if you have only a few results and you are giving the user a means to sort the list after they are already displayed in the browser, then JavaScript would be faster than heading back to the server for another DB pull.

Comment: The "metaprogramming" tag should be removed. `send` is at the core of all object-oriented languages, including Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try something like that :

```
Beer.all.send(:sort_by) {|b| b.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are special arguments in Ruby, they are not passed together with the regular arguments inside the parentheses. This doesn't have anything in particular to do with `send`. `send` is just a method like any other method, after all, it cannot change the syntax of Ruby.

Blocks are passed *after* all the other arguments, i.e. like this:

```
foo.bar(baz, qux) {|sillyname| do_stuff }
```